# Spacy: How to turn a verb into a noun?

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

How can I use Spacy to turn verbs into nouns? For example, the sentence

```
The shop is owned by the company.
```

has the verb `owned` in passive voice. I want to turn it into `owner` using Spacy.

Answer (score 1):

spaCy has no feature to do this. NLG, or modifying the input text to make new text, is considered out of scope for spaCy.

Even if you used an NLG library I'm not sure there's any standard way to do the kind of transformation you want.

Also there's nothing wrong with passive voice.